# I have to login in a page with vba without using internet explorer

Tags: html, vba

I have to login in the [page](https://industryoutlook.cmie.com/kommon/bin/sr.php?type=xls&kall=wrdxls&repnum=6250&frequency=M). But, I cannot use it.

Due to confidentiality I cannot provide the `username` and `password`.

Here is my code:

```
Sub checkdownload()


    Dim ur As String
    Dim pth As String
    ur = "http://industryoutlook.cmie.com/kommon/bin/sr.php?kall=wrddmp&type=dmp&tabcode=&frequency=A&colno=1&repnum=6254&dnbtn=1"

    Dim targetFolder As String, targetFileZip As String, targetFileCSV As String, targetFileTXT As String
    enter code here
    Dim wkbAll As Workbook
    Dim wkbTemp As Workbook
    Dim sDelimiter As String
    Dim newSheet As Worksheet
    Dim finalWorkSheetName As String

    pth = "E:\fitch intern\project 3"
    Debug.Print pth
    targetFolder = pth & "\temp"
    'msgbox url & targetFolder
    If Len(Dir(targetFolder, vbDirectory)) <> 0 Then
        On Error Resume Next
        Kill targetFolder & "\*.*"
        RmDir targetFolder
        MkDir targetFolder
    Else
        MkDir targetFolder
    End If
    targetFileZip = targetFolder & "\data.zip"
    targetFileCSV = targetFolder & "\data.csv"
    targetFileTXT = targetFolder & "\data.txt"

    DownloadZipFile targetFileZip, ur

End Sub

Sub DownloadZipFile(zipFileName As String, url As String)


Dim fso As Object
    Dim xmlObj As Object, stream As Object
    Dim strSource As String
    Dim cookie As String
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dim loginPageUrl As String, loginFormUrl As String, dataFormURL As String
    Dim loginFormData As String, dataFormData As String, responseData As Variant



    loginPageUrl = "https://industryoutlook.cmie.com/index.php"
    loginFormUrl = "https://industryoutlook.cmie.com/kommon/bin/sr.php?kall=wlogin"
    dataFormURL = url

    loginFormData = "username=........&password=...........&submit=Login"
    dataFormData = ""

    'Make a request to get the session cookie
    Call MakeSessionRequest("GET", loginPageUrl, loginFormData, cookie, True)
    'Make a request to submit the login form
    Call MakeSessionRequest("POST", loginFormUrl, loginFormData, cookie)
    'Make a request to submit the data form
    Call MakeSessionRequest("POST", dataFormURL, dataFormData, cookie)
    'Get the zip file contents from the server
    responseData = MakeSessionRequest("GET", dataFormURL, dataFormData, cookie)
    Debug.Print zipFileName

    'Write the returned zip file contents to a file on disk
    Set stream = CreateObject("ADODB.stream")
    Const adTypeBinary = 1
    Const adSaveCreateNotExist = 1
    Const adSaveCreateOverWrite = 2
    stream.Type = adTypeBinary
    stream.Open

    stream.write responseData

    stream.SaveToFile zipFileName, adSaveCreateOverWrite

    stream.Close

    Set stream = Nothing
    Set xmlObj = Nothing



End Sub

Function MakeSessionRequest(method As String, url As String, data As String, _
 ByRef cookie As String, Optional ByRef updateCookie = False) As Byte()

    If Len(cookie) = 0 Then cookie = "dummy=dummy;"
    httpReferrer = Trim(url)
    postVars = Trim(data)

Dim XMLHTTP As Object

    Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHttp")
    XMLHTTP.Open method, Trim(url), False

    If UCase(method) = "POST" Then
      XMLHTTP.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", _
                       "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    End If
    XMLHTTP.SetRequestHeader "Referer", httpReferrer 'in case the server cares
    XMLHTTP.SetRequestHeader "Cookie", "to deal with XMLHTTP bug"
    XMLHTTP.SetRequestHeader "Cookie", cookie
    XMLHTTP.Send postVars

    'wait for response
    While XMLHTTP.readyState <> 4
      XMLHTTP.waitForResponse 1000
    Wend

    ' extract the cookie data from the response header
    If updateCookie Then
      cookie = ""
      strheaders = XMLHTTP.getAllResponseHeaders()
      harr = Split(strheaders, "Set-Cookie: ")
      For kk = 1 To UBound(harr)
          theCookie = Left(harr(kk), InStr(harr(kk), "path=/") - 2)
          cookie = cookie & " " & theCookie
      Next
    End If

    'return the response body
    MakeSessionRequest = XMLHTTP.responseBody
    Set XMLHTTP = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this small script.

```
Sub DownloadData()

Dim lColumn As Long
Dim iCntr As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rwsToCheck As Long
Dim MyRange As Range
Dim iCounter As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")

' Get username and password from worksheet.  Not very secure, but this way the credentials are always sitting in the same spot and the user doesn't have to enter these each time.
' Alternative is to use an input box toprompt the user for crednetials.
UserName = Worksheets("ControlSheet").Range("A1").Value
Password = Worksheets("ControlSheet").Range("A2").Value

With ie
    .Visible = True
    .navigate "https://YOUR_URL_HERE"

' Wait for the page to fully load; you can't do anything if the page is not fully loaded
Do While .Busy Or _
    .readyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Loop

On Error Resume Next
'Credentials are passed to the site and the button is clicked (by the code).
ie.document.forms(0).all("username").Value = UserName
ie.document.forms(0).all("password").Value = Password
ie.document.forms(0).submit.Click

    ' Wait for the page to fully load; you can't do anything if the page is not fully loaded
    Do While .Busy Or _
        .readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    .navigate "ANOTHER_URL_AFTER_YOU_LOGIN"

    Do While .Busy Or _
        .readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

Set myDoc = ie.document

' MORE LOGIC HERE...

End Sub
```